# In MySQL, what does MONTH.DAYS do or return?

Tags: mysql, function

What does the function'MONTH.DAYS' do or return in MySQL?

It is embedded in the following query

```
IFNULL(ROUND((CST_TIME_ID - EST_TIME) / MONTH.DAYS), '')
```

Answer (score 1):

That's not a function. `MONTH` is the name of a table, `DAYS` is the name of a column in the table.

You presumably have a table something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE MONTH (
    MONTHNUM INT,
    DAYS INT,
    NAME VARCHAR(128)
);
INSERT INTO MONTH VALUES (1, 31, 'January'), (2, 28, 'February'), (3, 31, 'March'), ...;
```

The query must be joining with this table.